# tar: unable to include folder but exclude content

Tags: tar

I have a project folder with several directories

```
- archive 
- include
- lib
- src
- src/obj (obj is a subdirectory of src)
```

I would like `tar` to pack these directories and their contents into a `main.tar`, then I will the `main.tar` into the `archive` directory.

```
tar cvz \
    --exclude="*.obsolete" --exclude="*DS_Store" --exclude="./archive/*" \
    -f main.tar \
    ./archive ./include ./lib ./src
```

I would like to exclude the contents of the `archive` directory but still package the empty directory itself.  You can see I am also excluding some other stuff from various places, OSX likes to write .DS_Store files everywhere on my filesystem and I occasionally make copies of files and append `.obsolete` to the end while working on a new version.

Unfortunately, the empty `archive` directory is *not* included in `main.tar`.
According to [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/618702/in-tar-how-can-i-exclude-dir-contents-but-leave-empty-dir), my command *should* work.

How can the files be excluded from `archive` but the empty directory be packed into the tar file?

Answer (score 0):

**edit**

The following fails:

```
--exclude="./archive/*"
```

The following works:

```
--exclude="./archive/*.*"
```

So the whole command is:

```
tar cvz \
    --exclude="*.obsolete" --exclude="*DS_Store" --exclude="./archive/*.*" \
    -f main.tar \
    ./archive ./include ./lib ./src
```